# Get connection details from DSN-less string

Tags: php, odbc

Is it possible to get the database name and location from a Data Source Name?

```
$dsn = $_GET['dsn'];
$conn=odbc_connect($dsn,'','');
```

**Updated code**

```
$dsn = "JuniorDSN";
$conn=odbc_connect($dsn,'','') or die ("Can't connect to DSN");

$dsnarray = explode(";",$dsn);
$dsn0 = $dsnarray[0];

echo $dsn0;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now that you are aware of it, you can try doing it.

Comment: Without seeing any of the rest of your code, it seems like a _terrible_ idea to retrieve a dsn string from `$_GET/$_POST/anywyere`.  It could allow your website to serve someone else's data, or worse, trick your users into storing _their_ data with an unknown third party.

Comment: DSN strings are generally `;` delimited with `key=value` pairs. So `explode()` on `;` and subsequently `explode()` again on `=` in a loop to pluck out the values you need.  Or use a regular expression.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - it's an intranet site available only to admins. What am I exploding on? If I use the updated code above all I get is the the string "Junior DSN". If I explode on $conn I get a resource id error.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller - it doesn't take a genius to see the implicit question. But for your benefit: HOW?

Comment: @Dion All you have there is a simple string `JuniorDSN`. DSN's [often like all the examples here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) and would have useful info on driver, host, dbname, etc in them. Are you trying to reverse retrieve info about the db server based on the established odbc connection?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - correct. I set up JuniorDSN in Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Data Sources (ODBC) and created a link to an Access db. I want to tell the user exactly which db they're connecting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical DSN looks like this:

```
Driver={Driver name with space hence curly braces};dbname=testdb
```

So it's `parameter=value` pairs separated by semicolon. You can get info from that with just exploding string by `;` and then `=`, and trimming values with space from `{}`

You however are not using DSN but alias to predefined configuration, stored in `odbc.ini` (typically located in /etc/odbc.ini on unix like systems) or in windows registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI`). If you are using linux and have access to odbc.ini, you can parse it using [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php):

```
$connectionInfo = parse_ini_file('/etc/odbc.ini', true);
var_dump($connectionInfo['JuniorDSN']);
```

If you are on windows then you have to get this info from registry, with COM objects it should be possible.

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$odbcServer = $shell->RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\JuniorDSN\\Server");
```

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks for your help. I found it in: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\JuniorDSN\\DBQ"